# Show that $|\tanh(x) - P_4(x)| \le 0.005$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I have to establish the inequality $|\tanh(x) - P_4(x)| \le 0.005$ for $|x| < \frac{1}{2}$. I have established that $\tanh(x) < x$ for all $x>0$. I now have to establish that $x \to \tanh x - P_4(x)$ is growing in $(0,\infty)$. But I am not sure how to do so?
I know that $P_4 = x- \frac{1}{3}x^3$.

Comment: Try to compute &P_{5} & There's theorem saying error is estimated by next polynomial

Comment: $P_5$ is $x-\frac{1}{3}x^3+\frac{2}{15}x^4$ but how can I use it?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "$x \to \tanh x - P_4(x)$ is growing in $(0,\infty)$" ? And clarify what is $P_n$? I'm guessing $n^{\rm th}$ degree Taylor polynomial for $\tanh x$.

Comment: You are correct, it is Taylor polynomials